# Swift 5 - Simulator launching with white screen - Instruments

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments, retain-cycle, xcode11.3

I was trying to check the memory leak for my project using Instruments. Although, I could launch instruments but while its running the simulator is launching with white screen only. So that I could not debug my application to find the retain cycle. I am using **Xcode Version 11.3 (11C29)**. Can anyone have faced such that issue. And share your thoughts to get the status of memory leak.

Comment: Usage of instruments is kinda outdated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149983/how-to-fix-memory-leaks-in-ios-applications/60157622#60157622

Comment: Although, I had got the issue with instruments while launching simulator. If it is outdated, it is still existing in Xcode. That's why I shared my query here. Great, I have found the solution with my friend's (Arun) support. And shared the same solution below as an answer.

Comment: To be honest I haven’t used instruments for a long time now. I think it provides more debugging details. Additionally with the ‘Allocation’ you can identify memory growth which then you have to narrow it down yourself and figure out if it’s from a leak, abandoned memory or just cached memory. I don’t think Xcode itself gives a nice memory graph timeline. It just gives you a current level of app memory consumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, We have got the solution for this question. Please follow the below steps to launch the instruments,

**Run** the app -> **Debug Navigator** -> Click **CPU** -> Click **Profile in Instruments** button in the Right window -> Then Click the **Transfer** button in the pop up window.

[image: ScreenShot1]

It will launch the Instruments with the selected project, Now you can check the retain cycle of your project through your application.

Great!!! You can have the **INSTRUMENTS** now :-)

[image]

Even, You can have the UI of your app to test the memory leak.

[image]